# How do i generate refresh and access token for Google Play Developers API

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-developers-console, play-billing-library

My goal is to validate user purchases on google server as described here > [Purchases.products: get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get)

but i need to authorise the request > [Authorisation Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization)

According to [Google Play Developer API Authorization Doccumentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization) in order to generate access and refresh token :

> "... sending a POST request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token with the following fields set:

```
grant_type=authorization_code
code=<the code from the previous step>
client_id=<the client ID token created in the APIs Console>
client_secret=<the client secret corresponding to the client ID>
redirect_uri=<the URI registered with the client ID>
```

A successful response will contain your tokens in JSON format:

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29.ZStBkRnGyZ2mUYOLgls7QVBxOg82XhBCFo8UIT5gM",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : "1/zaaHNytlC3SEBX7F2cfrHcqJEa3KoAHYeXES6nmho"
}
```

> "

i successfully generated code, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri from console.developers.google.com but when i send the POST request

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=my_generated_codeA&client_id=generated_client_id&client_secret=generated_client_secret&redirect_uri=my_redirect_uri

i get the the following response when i used [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/):

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing header: Content-Type"
}
```

with status code = 400

i get the the following response when i used Chrome :

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

How can i get the right response?

Comment: How do you send POST request? Are you doing it through a browser, Postman, java code or something else? If you send it using java then provide your source code.

Comment: i did it through postman and browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=my_generated_codeA&client_id=generated_client_id&client_secret=generated_client_secret&redirect_uri=my_redirect_uri` is GET request, it's not POST request because there is no request body.

Also, when using Postman the response

```
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "Missing header: Content-Type"
}
```

means that you select the wrong header. You should select `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` option in `Body`tab in Postman. Then write down key pair value. You will get something like this:

[image]